# Why are edits in the first 5 minutes not recorded?

Tags: discussion, edits, grace-period

What is the purpose of the 5 minute grace period for editing a new post? Is there a reason edits during that time aren't displayed as normal? I don't see the rationale for such a feature.

Comment: Many tiny edits are to be expected in the first few minutes. The result of that would be many bumps (I assume) and a rapid progress to a self-edit Community Wiki conversion. Perhaps that's part of the motivation.

Comment: Jeff insisted on it. See the [grace-period tag wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/grace-period/info).